# How do I resolve a "No reply address provided" error when using MSAL.js?

Tags: azure, localhost, single-sign-on, msal.js

I've copied the example app at this repository to try to implement single sign-on: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-v2.

Into the msalConfig's auth object within the authConfig.js file I substituted my application's clientId and authority values, and used a redirectUrl value of "http://localhost:5500" since I need to test this locally first.

I'm getting the appropriate SSO popup that processes and then halts with the following error:

> AADSTS900971: No reply address provided.

Is there a server-side setting that has to be in place for this to work? Can this be tested from localhost (or 127.0.0.1) on my machine?

Comment: Just wondering if you have configured the redirect URI in the application configuration in Azure AD?

Comment: @GauravMantri I don't believe so, but I also don't control the server side of this at all. What value would need to be used in that field on the server? Would that still present an issue for trying to test this SSO flow from my local machine?

Comment: You would need to put a redirect URI in your application configuration in Azure AD and that should match with the redirect value you put in authConfig.js file (`http://localhost:5500`).

Comment: Is this issue resolved by putting a redirect URI in your application configuration in Azure AD?

Comment: You need to ensure that the `redirectUrl` configured in the **authConfig.js** file is consistent with the `redirectUrl` configured in **Azure AD**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary comments are posted as answers.

Like I said in the comments, you need to ensure that the `redirectUrl` configured in the **authConfig.js** file is consistent with the  `redirectUrl` configured in **Azure AD**.

[image]

Comment: An example of redirect URIs is like : https://{app-name-in-Azure-AD}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Comment: Does it `redirectURL` or `redirectUri`? According to the sample it is mentioned as `redirectUri`. 
REF: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-react-samples/react-router-sample/src/authConfig.js#L19`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the config was set correctly, however I hadn't noticed that the sample code I had copied to initialize MSAL (for Angular) was using hard coded values instead of reading from the config. Once I updated it to read the redirectUri and postLogoutRedirectUri from the config all was good.